# Unable to locate element using regex

Tags: regex, cucumber, watir

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'watir'
require 'rspec'
require 'cucumber'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
```

I am receiving the following error and wondering how to construct the proper (See error below ) Watir syntax to handle  my regex to set  text in a filed. The element is dynamic . The regex simply drops the four digits and keeps the  consistent part of the id ( see below).  By the way since the element Id is itself dynamic neither xpath or css selection methods worked.

```
Unable to locate element
```

Cucumber watir (step)

```
browser.text_field(:id => '(id=numberfield-)\d\d\d\d(-inputEl').double_click # set '10'
```

And changes upon refresh . See the html below

HTML:

```
<input id="numberfield-2840-inputEl" data-ref="inputEl" type="text" role="spinbutton" size="1" name="Quantity" class="x-form-field x-form-text x-form-text-default " autocomplete="off" componentid="numberfield-2840">
```

Comment: You're `double_click`'ing on a `text_field`?  And shouldn't your regex locator look more like `text_field(:id => /numberfield-\d\d\d\d-inputEl/)`?

Comment: To expand on what @orde said, you are passing in a String (ie exact text match) rather than a Regexp (ie a pattern or partial match).

Comment: The double click was just to see if it got that far and clicked the field, Thanks for the feedback.  Think I can resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a real regular expression object, not a string containing regex notation

```
browser.text_field(:id => /numberfield-\d\d\d\d-inputEl/)
```

However, I would caution you that selecting via regex can be somewhat slow in webdriver and hence also in watir.  You might want to use another attribute of the input element, or CSS selectors.

without seeing more of the html I'm not sure what is unique for that input field, but examples that might work for you would include

```
browser.text_field(:name => 'Quantity')
browser.text_field(:data_ref => 'inputEl')
```

The last one is something I've used a lot, since watir supports any of the custom "data dash something" attributes, just substitute a underscore for the dash when using that as the label for what attribute to look for.

(Note: I'm sorta cheating since the answer is already in the comments to the question, but there were a few points I wanted to make, and this allows us to have an accepted answer, which is nice for anyone with a similar issue)

Answer (score 0):

I would select the field with a CSS selector on the name:

```
browser.text_field(:css => "input[name='Quantity']")
```